# How to install fluxctl on WSL

Tags: kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install [fluxctl](https://www.weave.works/blog/install-fluxctl-and-manage-your-deployments-easily) on my WSL (Ubuntu 18.04). I saw the official recommendation to install on Linux is through [snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io/fluxctl) but WSL flavors in general does not support snap yet.

I know the other option is to compile from source or download binary. Is there another way to install fluxctl on WSL through a package/application manager?

Comment: Snap can be run in WSL2 which is available in slow and fast insider build now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if someone had made a PPA but it seems unlikely. Also FWIW they publish Windows binaries too, right next to the Linux ones.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes the package manager I use for windows already has it listed and works well. As a have a dev setup going on my WSL, was curious.

Comment: Ops tools on linux are definitely less organized. So many people use Mac laptops that Brew is the only major centralized system for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found very easy steps to install fluxctl in wsl

```
sudo wget https://github.com/fluxcd/flux/releases/download/1.17.1/fluxctl_windows_amd64 -O /usr/bin/fluxctl && sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/fluxctl

$ fluxctl version
```